# Jmeter+Jenkins+File not found exception

Tags: java, jenkins, jmeter, extentreports

//    **Am running a meter script integrated with jenkins,when trying to send report it complains about "file not found exception"
    have tried it locally it works fine but once moved on to the server getting the error.
    have tried getting from workspace, it creates folders but doesn't have the file dropped and am using extent reporting any sujjestions/inputs is really appreciated

DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
        DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=smtp.googlemail.com, user=rohith@cowboyaliens.com, password=
        DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2 
        DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
        DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
        DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
        DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
        MAIL FROM:
        250 2.1.0 OK w2-v6sm5908675wre.57 - gsmtp
        RCPT TO:
        250 2.1.5 OK w2-v6sm5908675wre.57 - gsmtp
        DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
        DEBUG SMTP:   rohith@cowboyaliens.com
        DATA
        354  Go ahead w2-v6sm5908675wre.57 - gsmtp
        DEBUG SMTP: IOException while sending, closing, THROW: 
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/alienbuilder/.jenkins/workspace/Sling-API-Automation/Sling/Report.html (No such file or directory)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
            at javax.activation.FileDataSource.getInputStream(FileDataSource.java:97)
            at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:305)
            at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1692)
            at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:996)
            at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:561)
            at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:84)
            at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:889)
            at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:317)
            at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1692)
            at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1913)
            at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1315)
            at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.smtp.sampler.protocol.SendMailCommand.execute(SendMailCommand.java:303)
            at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.smtp.sampler.SmtpSampler.executeMessage(SmtpSampler.java:169)
            at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.smtp.sampler.SmtpSampler.sample(SmtpSampler.java:146)
            at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:491)
            at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:425)
            at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:254)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        summary +      1 in 00:00:05 =    0.2/s Avg:  4262 Min:  4262 Max:  4262 Err:     1 (100.00%) Active: 0 Started: 1 Finished: 1
        summary =      5 in 00:00:35 =    0.1/s Avg:  6944 Min:     2 Max: 30225 Err:     2 (40.00%)
        Tidying up ...    @ Wed Oct 24 15:00:34 SAST 2018 (1540386034868)
        ... end of run
        Archiving artifacts
        Email was triggered for: Always
        Sending email for trigger: Always
        Sending email to: rohith@cowboyaliens.com rohithreddy.polusani@absa.co.za
        Connection error sending email, retrying once more in 10 seconds...
        Connection error sending email, retrying once more in 10 seconds...
        Failed after second try sending email
        Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: Show your jenkins configuration

Comment: Show your jenkins log

Comment: have uploaded on the question, let me know if you need anything specific for further information

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask questions.